# add new fields on registration page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website, and I want to add new fields when user register, like phone number and street address.

I know how to add input fields in registration form, but I cannot understand how to save this fields in database during registration, like other details as username are saved.

How to do that?

**UPDATE:**

```
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register')
```

the function myplugin_user_register() is called after main user details like username, email was inserted in database, or all details will be saved at same time.

I also want to save extra fields in other table, in $wpdb->users, how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding custom user field is like adding custom field to post.

It can be done with the help of the following filters :

1. '[register_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form)'
2. '[register_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post)'
3. '[user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_registe)'

You can see an example of the complete process here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

If you need to allow the modification from the user from his profile page, check the filters personal_options_update and edit_user_profile_update.

Comment: Its really not recommended to alter internal WP table structure ($wpdb->users is WP users table). Post/User "meta" table are here to avoid that, it allows you to do everything you want without modifying wb db structure.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to dip into code yourself, there are a few very simple plugins that will do the job for you like : [cimy user extra fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/screenshots/) or [User Registration Aide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-registration-aide/)..

You could search more at the same place ( [Plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=user%20extra&sort=) )

Regarding your Update :

what you should use is [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) , [`add_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta), [`delete_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta) and [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) , all of which act exactly like the post_meta ( custom fields )  with the sole difference that they are assigned to users instead of post . think of them like "custom fields for users"

and  just like RafH said , there is no need to add tables, and actually it is a bad practice when working with wordpress, and a receipt for future headaches.

Answer (score 1):

**user_register** action hook is used to save the extra field data to database as user meta submitted by custom registration forms.Basically , when a new user is created ,the user id is passed to this action hook as argument and used to save the extra field in user meta.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_save_extra_fields', 10, 1 );

function my_save_extra_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['mobile_no'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'mobile_no', $_POST['mobile_no']);

}
```